# jspm init returns "jspm init has not yet been implemented"

Tags: node.js, npm, jspm

I just installed jspm globally using npm on Mac OS (`sudo npm install jspm -g`). Now when I run `jspm init`, I see the following console output:

```
err (jspm) jspm init has not yet been implemented.
```

When I run `jspm` I get the following output:

```
2.0.0-beta.6
Running against global jspm install.
```

Is `jspm init` still a valid command?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: @SuperAaz no, unfortunately I didn't. I ended up using something else. Possibly yarn or something other.

Answer (score 2):

Initially I was trying with `jspm@2.0.0-beta.7` and was getting an error. When I switched to an old version of `jspm` (0.16.55), it worked.

1. `npm install -g jspm@0.16.55`
2. `jspm init`

It works after this.